# DomPDF strange page breaks

Tags: cakephp, dompdf, page-break

I'm using DomPDF with CakePdf to generate pdf. Good tool, but juste one thing I don't understand : the behavior of "page-break-before" in CSS. Usually it works pretty well : pages break when I want, but sometimes it becomes crazy and causes many page breaks inside, or before. Unbelievable.

- Here's an example of pdf generated with DomPDF, look at page 3, there's a blank whereas it should not (on other examples, it works well, no blank) : [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4phmvoq0mwnthc/Convention-SC000122.pdf)
- **[edit]** and an HTML version as well : [link](http://scio.fr/pages/test-convention.html)

Now the code source (there are comments for each page) :

```
<style type="text/css">
    @page {
        margin: .5cm;
    }
    body {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 80px;
        font-family: 'helvetica', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    ul, li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    ul {
        margin-left: 40px;
    }
    p, li {
        font-size: .875em;
        line-height: 1.6em;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #header, #footer {
        position: fixed;
        /*left: 0;
        right: 0;*/
    }
    #header {
        top: 0;
    }
    #footer {
        /*top: 1005px;*/
        height: 60px;
        bottom: 0;
        background: #E28900;
    }
    #headerDiv {
        border-top-width: 6px;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-top-color: #E28900;
        /*padding-top: 20px;*/
    }
    img#logo {
        position: absolute;
        top: 26px;
        left: 0;
        width: 120px;
    }
    #footerDiv {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
    #footerDiv p {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: .75em;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #footer .pagenum {
        position: absolute;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: .75em;
        font-weight: bold;
        bottom: 25px;
        right: 10px;
    }
    #footer .pagenum:before { content: counter(page); }

    h1#convention {
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2.8em;
        line-height: 1em;
        padding: 250px 0 0 0;
        color: #E28900;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-family: 'titre';
    }
    h1#convention span {
        display: block;
    }
    h1#convention small {
        display: block;
        margin: 20px 0 0;
        padding: 0 100px 0 100px;

        font-family: 'helvetica';
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: .4em;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        color: #006D93;
        text-transform: none;
    }

    #adresse_client {
        position: absolute;
        left: 70px;
        top: 680px;
    }
    #adresse_scio {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: right;
        right: 70px;
        top: 800px;
    }
    #adresse_client p, #adresse_scio p {
        font-size: .9em;
    }
    #adresse_client b, #adresse_scio b {
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #006D93;
        font-size: .75em;
    }
    #adresse_scio a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #E28900;
    }

    .page-break {
        page-break-before: always;
    }

    /* style page 2 */
    #adresse_client2 {
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 70px;
        margin-right: 70px;
    }
    #adresse_client2 p {
        color: #006D93;
        text-align: right;
    }
    #lettre {
        margin: 0 70px;
    }
    #lettre p {
        line-height: 1.2em;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    #lettre #signature {
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
    #lettre #signature p {
        text-align: right;
    }

    /* style page 3 */
    #headerFormation {
        margin: 0 70px 30px 70px;
    }
    #headerFormation td {
        padding: 10px 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    #headerFormation h3 {
        display: inline;
        color: #000;
        font-size: .85em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #contenuFormation {
        margin: 0 70px 0;
    }
    h2#nomFormation {
        font-family: 'share';
        color: #006D93;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.6em;
        line-height: 1em;
        margin: 10px 70px;
    }

    /* style page 4 */
    #headerConvention {
        margin: 0 0 5px 70px;
    }
    #headerConvention h2 {
        color: #006D93;
        font-family: 'share';
        font-size: 2em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #conventionPersonnes {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    #conventionPersonnes td {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 10px 0;
        font-size: .85em;
    }
    #conventionPersonnes small {
        color: #006D93;
    }
    #contenuConvention p, #contenuConvention li {
        font-size: .85em;
        line-height: 1.4em;
    }
    #contenuConvention {
        margin: 0 70px 0;
    }
    #contenuConvention h3 {
        margin: 20px 0 5px 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'helvetica';
        font-size: .85em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #E28900;
    }
    #contenuConvention h4 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: .75em;
        margin: 0 20px 10px 20px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #conventionSignatures {
        margin-top: 40px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    #conventionSignatures strong {
        color: #006D93;
    }
    #conventionSignatures td {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #conventionSignatures td.first {
        border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    /* style page 5 */
    #cgv {
        margin: 0 70px;
    }
    #cgv h2 {
        font-family: 'helvetica';
        font-size: .85em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #006D93;
    }
    #cgv p, #cgv li {
        font-size: .625em;
    }
</style>

<!-- HEADER, FOOTER -->
<div id="header">
  <div id="headerDiv"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="footerDiv">
        <p>Immeuble CIT 3 rue de l'Arrivée 75749 Paris Cedex 15 / SAS au capital de 50 00 0 € - RCS de Paris 751 962 119</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pagenum"></div>
</div>

<!-- PAGE 1 -->
<?php echo $this->Html->image('/home/scio/app/webroot/img/scio-conseil-et-formation.png', array('alt' => 'Scio conseil & formation', 'id' => 'logo')); ?>
<h1 id="convention">
    <span>Convention de formation</span>
    <small><?php echo $stage['Formation']['libelle']; ?></small>
</h1>

<div id="adresse_client">
    <p><b>Pour :</b></p>
    <p><strong><?php echo strtoupper($client['SocietesEtablissement']['name']); ?></strong></p>
    <p><?php echo $client['SocietesEtablissement']['adresse1']; ?></p>
    <?php
    if(!empty($client['SocietesEtablissement']['adresse2']))
        echo '<p>'. $client['SocietesEtablissement']['adresse2'] .'</p>';
    ?>
    <p><?php echo $client['SocietesEtablissement']['code_postal'] . ' ' . $client['SocietesEtablissement']['ville']; ?></p>
</div>
<div id="adresse_scio">
    <p><b>Scio, Conseil & Formation</b></p>
    <p><strong>Joël NICOLAS</strong></p>
    <p>Associé Dirigeant</p>
    <p>Tel. 01 83 94 79 05</p>
    <p><a href="mailto:joel.nicolas@scio.fr">joel.nicolas@scio.fr</a></p>
</div>


<!-- PAGE 2 -->
<div class="page-break">
    <div id="adresse_client2">
        <p><strong><?php echo strtoupper($client['SocietesEtablissement']['name']); ?></strong></p>
        <p><?php echo $client['SocietesEtablissement']['adresse1']; ?></p>
        <?php
        if(!empty($client['SocietesEtablissement']['adresse2']))
            echo '<p>'. $client['SocietesEtablissement']['adresse2'] .'</p>';
        ?>
        <p><?php echo $client['SocietesEtablissement']['code_postal'] . ' ' . $client['SocietesEtablissement']['ville']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div id="lettre">
        <p>Paris,<br />
        <?php
        $listeJours = array(
            1 => "lundi",
            2 => "mardi",
            3 => "mercredi",
            4 => "jeudi",
            5 => "vendredi",
            6 => "samedi",
            7 => "dimanche"
        );
        $listeMois = array(
            "01"    =>  "janvier",
            "02"    =>  "février",
            "03"    =>  "mars",
            "04"    =>  "avril",
            "05"    =>  "mai",
            "06"    =>  "juin",
            "07"    =>  "juillet",
            "08"    =>  "août",
            "09"    =>  "septembre",
            "10"    =>  "octobre",
            "11"    =>  "novembre",
            "12"    =>  "décembre"
        );
        $dateHisto = strtotime($histo['CommandeHisto']['histo_date']);
        $jourDateHisto = date('d', $dateHisto);
        $journeeDateHisto = date('N', $dateHisto);
        $moisDateHisto = date('m', $dateHisto);
        $anneeDateHisto = date('Y', $dateHisto);
        ?>
        <?php echo 'Le ' . $listeJours[$journeeDateHisto] . ' ' . $jourDateHisto . ' ' . $listeMois[$moisDateHisto] . ' ' . $anneeDateHisto . '</p>'; ?>
        <br />
        <p>Objet : Convention de Formation</p>
        <br />
        <p>Madame, Monsieur,</p>
        <br />
        <p>Nous vous prions de bien vouloir trouver ci-joint notre offre concernant :</p>
        <br />
        <?php if(empty($stage['Commande']['formation_id']) && empty($stage['Commande']['event_group_id'])) { ?>
            <p><strong><?php echo $stage['Commande']['intitule']; ?></strong></p>
            <br />
            <p>Ainsi que les éléments cités en annexe ci-dessous :</p>
            <br />
            <ul>
                <li>la Convention de formation </li>
                <li>les conditions générales de vente SCIO Conseil & Formation</li>
            </ul>
            <br />
            <p>Pour accord de votre part, nous vous remercions de bien vouloir nous retourner complété, daté et paraphé l’exemplaire de la "Convention de formation".</p>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <p><strong><?php echo $stage['Formation']['libelle'] . ' - réf. ' . $stage['Formation']['reference']; ?></strong></p>
            <br />
            <p>Ainsi que les éléments cités en annexe ci-dessous :</p>
            <br />
            <ul>
                <li>le programme de formation</li>
                <li>la Convention de formation </li>
                <li>les conditions générales de vente SCIO Conseil & Formation</li>
            </ul>
            <br />
            <p>Pour accord de votre part, nous vous remercions de bien vouloir nous retourner complété, daté et paraphé l’exemplaire de la "Convention de formation".</p>
            <br />    
            <p>Si le coût de la prestation est pris en charge par un organisme collecteur, veuillez cocher le libellé prévu à cet effet et préciser ses coordonnées sur le feuillet "Convention de formation".</p>
            <br />
        <?php } ?>
        <p>Nous espérons que notre offre répondra à vos attentes, et restons à votre disposition pour toute information complémentaire,</p>
        <br />
        <p>Nous vous prions d’agréer, Madame, Monsieur, l’expression de nos salutations distinguées.</p>

        <div id="signature">
            <p>Joël NICOLAS </p>
            <p><i>Dirigeant</i></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php if(!empty($stage['Commande']['formation_id'])) { ?>
    <!-- PAGE 3 -->
    <div class="page-break"></div>
    <!-- Si on met un page-break à un élément qui fait plusieurs pages, il y a des sauts de pages bizarres -->
    <div>
        <h2 id="nomFormation"><?php echo $stage['Formation']['libelle'] ; ?></h2>
        <div id="headerFormation">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="50%" align="left"><h3><small style="font-weight: normal;">Programme de formation : </small> <?php echo 'réf. ' . $stage['Formation']['reference']; ?></h3></td>
                      <td width="50%" align="right"><h3><small style="font-weight: normal;">Sous-gamme</small> <?php echo $gamme['Gamme']['libelle']; ?></h3></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="contenuFormation">
            <p><span style="color: #E28900;">Personnes concernées :</span> <?php echo $stage['Formation']['cible']; ?></p>
            <br />
            <p><span style="color: #E28900;">Objectifs pédagogiques :</span></p>
            <?php echo $stage['Formation']['objectifs']; ?>
            <br />
            <p><span style="color: #E28900;">Programme détaillé :</span></p>
            <div id="programme">
                    <?php echo $stage['Formation']['programme']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<!-- PAGE 4 -->
<div class="page-break">
    <div id="headerConvention">
        <h2>Convention de formation</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="contenuConvention">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" id="conventionPersonnes">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%" valign="top">
                    <p><small>Entre :</small></p>
                    <p><strong>SCIO Conseil & Formation</strong><br />
                    Immeuble CIT<br />
                    3 rue de l’Arrivée<br />
                    75015 PARIS<br />
                  <i>RCS de Paris : 751 962 119</i></p>
                </td>
                <td width="50%" valign="top">
                    <p><small>Et :</small></p>
                    <p><strong><?php echo strtoupper($client['SocietesEtablissement']['name']); ?></strong><br />
                    <?php echo $client['SocietesEtablissement']['adresse1']; ?><br />
                    <?php
                    if(!empty($client['SocietesEtablissement']['adresse2']))
                        echo $client['SocietesEtablissement']['adresse2'] .'<br />';
                    ?>
                    <?php echo $client['SocietesEtablissement']['code_postal'] . ' ' . $client['SocietesEtablissement']['ville']; ?><br />
                  <?php echo '<i>SIRET : ' . $client['SocietesEtablissement']['siret'] . '</i>'; ?></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php if(empty($stage['Commande']['formation_id']) && empty($stage['Commande']['event_group_id'])) { ?>
            <?php
            echo '<h3>Objet de la prestation : '. $stage['Commande']['intitule'] .'</h3>';
            echo html_entity_decode($stage['Commande']['commentaires']);
            echo '<h3>Conditions tarifaires & facturation</h3>';
            echo '<ul>';
                echo '<li>Coût de la prestation : <strong>'. number_format($stage['Commande']['montant'],2,',',' ').' € HT *</strong></li>';
                if(isset($remise) && !empty($remise)) {
                    echo '<li>';
                        echo 'Remise : <strong>-'. number_format($remise['Invoice']['montant'],2,',',' ') .' €</strong>';
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            echo '</ul>';
            ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <h3>1. Objet de la prestation</h3>
            <h4><?php echo $stage['Formation']['libelle'] . ' (' . $stage['Formation']['reference'] . ')'; ?></h4>
            <p><small style="font-size: .8125em; line-height: 1.2em; color: #888;">Cette prestation s’inscrit dans les actions de formation professionnelle mentionnées à l’article L6313-1 du code du travail  Le client reconnaît avoir pris connaissance des conditions particulières relatives aux prestations de formation et déclare en accepter les termes.</small></p>

            <h3>2. Conditions d'exécution de la prestation</h3>
            <ul>
                    <li>Nombre de participants : <strong><?php echo $stage['Commande']['participants']; ?></strong></li>
                <li>Nombre de jours : 
                    <strong>
                                            <?php
                                            $duree = explode('.', $stage['Formation']['duree']);
                                            if($duree[1] == 5) {
                                                    echo number_format($stage['Formation']['duree'],'1',',',' ');
                                            } else {
                            echo $duree[0];
                                            }
                                            ?> jours
                    </strong>
                </li>
                <li>Nombre de sessions : <strong><?php echo $stage['Formation']['duree_nb']; ?></strong></li>
            </ul>

            <h3>3. Dates d'exécution</h3>
            <ul>
                    <li>
                    Date(s) de session(s) : 
                    <strong>
                        <?php
                        if(empty($stage['Commande']['event_group_id']) && $stage['Formation']['type'] == 'interentreprise') {
                            echo 'à définir';
                        } else {
                            if($dates[0]['debut'] == $dates[0]['fin']) {
                                echo 'le ' . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dates[0]['debut']));
                            } else {
                                echo 'du ' . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dates[0]['debut'])) . ' au ' . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dates[0]['fin']));
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </strong>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Lieu : 
                    <strong>
                        <?php
                        if(empty($stage['Commande']['event_group_id']) && $stage['Formation']['type'] == 'interentreprise') {
                            echo 'à définir';
                        } else {
                            echo $dates['EventPlace']['adresse'] . ' ' . $dates['EventPlace']['code_postal'] . ' ' . $dates['EventPlace']['ville'];
                        }
                        ?>
                    </strong>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <h3>4. Éléments pédagogiques</h3>
            <ul>
                    <li><?php echo strip_tags($stage['Formation']['moyens']); ?></li>
            </ul>

            <h3>5. Conditions tarifaires & facturation</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Coût de la session de formation : <strong><?php echo number_format($stage['Commande']['montant'],2,',',' '); ?> € HT *</strong></li>
                <?php
                if(isset($remise) && !empty($remise)) {
                    echo '<li>';
                        echo 'Remise : <strong>'. number_format($remise['Invoice']['montant'],2,',',' ') .' €</strong>';
                    echo '</li>';
                    echo '<li>';
                        echo 'Montant après remise : <strong>'. number_format(($stage['Commande']['montant']+$remise['Invoice']['montant']),2,',',' ') .' €</strong>';
                    echo '</li>';
                }
                ?>
                <li>Facturation : <strong><?php echo $stage['Commande']['info_paiement']; ?></strong></li>
                <li>Prise en charge OPCA : <strong>................................. € HT</strong></li>
                <li>Prise en charge Client : <strong>................................. € HT</strong></li>
                <li>Autre : .....................................................................................................................................</li>
            </ul>
        <?php } ?>

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" id="conventionSignatures">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%" height="100" class="first" valign="top">
                    <p><strong>Pour SCIO Conseil & Formation</strong></p>
                    <p><small>À ................................. le .................................</small></p>
                    <p><small>Signature :</small></p>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->image('/home/scio/app/webroot/img/manager/signature-joel-nicolas.jpg', array('alt' => 'Joël Nicolas pour : SCIO Conseil & Formation')); ?>
                </td>
                <td width="50%" valign="top">
                    <p><strong>Pour le client</strong></p>
                    <p><small>À ................................. le .................................</small></p>
                    <p><small>Signature & cachet :</small></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <p><small style="font-size: .8125em; line-height: 1.2em; color: #888;">* Les conditions proposées dans la présente convention sont valables 3 mois à compter de la date de signature apposée par SCIO Conseil & Formation</small></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Since rendering issues are typically due to how dompdf parses the HTML/CSS it's more helpful to post the HTML document rather than the PHP that creates the HTML document. Otherwise we have to fill in the variables when debugging. So, can you post the source HTML? It also helps to know which version of dompdf you're using.

Comment: I've added an HTML version, but it doesn't look like the PDF version at all !! ^^ Hope it will... help you to help me. :)